# Gnome equivalent to Windows Media Player's taskbar controls

Tags: gnome, media-player

Is there anything on GNOME that allows you to have controls for a media player in a panel? Like what Windows Media Player has that lets you minimise it to the taskbar, and use volume and playback controls there.

Something similar to this:

[image: WMP in Taskbar]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"[Music Applet](http://www.kuliniewicz.org/music-applet/) is a small, simple GNOME panel applet that lets you control a variety of different music players from the panel."

I haven't tried this software, I just googled it.

**Edit:** [Lifehacker](http://lifehacker.com/5364979/music-applet-controls-tunes-from-the-linux-system-tray) has taken notice, and they appear to have the applet running in Ubuntu. They also raise the point that you should search for the applet in your distro's repositories before installing from source.

Comment: Yeah, Kevin got it running. Looks like a good solution.

Comment: It's not in the ubuntu repos, and the site doesn't work for me, but it is what I wanted, and it's evidently working for others (my ISP's DNS can be rather dodgy at times).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure if this is what you are looking for, but banshee has an extension called "mini mode" that only provides the media controls. Below is a screenshot of what it looks like:

[image]

Comment: No that's not what I meant, I added a picture.

Answer (score 0):

[AWN](http://wiki.awn-project.org/Main_Page) provides an [applet](http://wiki.awn-project.org/Media_Icons_Applet) through which you can control the playback, if you use AWN.